# cannot succeed in using Convert.FromBase64String on... base64string in C#/.NET Core

Tags: c#, base64, asp.net-core

I am using [Cropper](https://github.com/fengyuanchen/cropper) to crop an image in a web application, and then send the result as a base64 string to my `ASP.NET Core` controller. So far, I've not figured out the data type necessary to send it correctly, but in the meantime `dynamic` or a custom data type works;

I crop the image, and then try to send it in;

```
var base64string = cropperWidgetInstance.getCroppedCanvas().toDataUrl('image/jpeg');
$http.post('url', { data: base64string });
```

in my ASP.NET Controller, I'm receiving the data like this;

```
public async Task<IActionResult> SaveCroppedImage([FromBody] dynamic data) {

}
```

this gives me an object called `data`, with a property itself called `data` that contains a string like this;

`data:image/jpeg;base64,/9j/4AAQSkZJRgABAQAAAQABAAD/2wBDAAMCAgICAgMCAgIDAwMDBAYEBAQEBAgGBgUGCQgKCgkICQkKDA8MCgsOCwkJDRENDg8QEBEQCgwSExIQEw8QEBD/2wBDAQMDAwQDBAgEBAgQCwkLEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBD/wAARCAGTAswD ....`

This looks like it should work fine, but when I try to use

`Convert.FromBase64String(data.data)`

It gives me the exception

> icrosoft.CSharp.RuntimeBinder.RuntimeBinderException: The best overloaded method match for 'System.Convert.FromBase64String(string)' has some invalid arguments

I really have no idea what is going wrong here. I can't find any article on the topic that doesn't follow the exact same steps of just using `Convert.FromBase64String`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you have data in form of :

```
data:image/jpeg;base64,/9j/4AAQSkZJRgABAQAAAQABAAD/2wBDAAMCAgICAgMCAgIDAwM
DBAYEBAQEBAgGBgUGCQgKCgkICQkKDA8MCgsOCwkJDRENDg8QEBEQCgwSExIQEw8QEBD/2wBDA
QMDAwQDBAgEBAgQCwkLEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBA
QEBAQEBAQEBD/wAARCAGTAswD ....
```

if you want to convert it in FromBase64String then you have to remove "data:image/jpeg;base64," from your string and then convert it to FromBase64String

you can replace it like below code

```
string strdata = "data:image/jpeg;base64,/9j/4AAQSkZJRgABAQAAAQABAAD/2wBDAAMC.... 

var strstring = strdata.replace("data:image/jpeg;base64,", '');
```

and then try to convert it

```
Convert.FromBase64String(strstring);
```

it works for me try this..

Comment: I think I'd just do `Convert.FromBase64String(strstring.Substring(23));` or something along those lines. Why do a string compare?

Comment: Neither of those work, it seems. I continue to get the same error.

Comment: They work for us. Maybe you're doing something else wrong?

Comment: I have given you exactly what I am doing.

Comment: No you haven't. Since we've give two solutions your example doesn't show trying those solutions. On the other hand your error suggests something else. What type is `data.data`?

Comment: I found the problem, __I__ wasn't replicating your exact example correctly by converting to a `string` first. I was still passing the `dynamic`

Comment: No, you're right. I mis-typed. Thank you, it seems to work now.